# Azure RemoteApp Collection with AzureVM

Tags: azure, azure-vm-role, remoteapp

I'm new in Azure and trying to add a custom application in my azure RemoteApp. I have created an `Azure VM (windows 2012 R2 Evaluation)` and an azure RemoteApp collection. I have added my custom application in VM at path `c:\Customs\MyTestApplication\TestApplication.exe` and also in remoteapp collectio have published this custom via path `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Customs\MyTestApplication\TestApplication.exe`.

But when I am runing `Azure RemoteApp` client I see my test application but cannot run. It cannt find the test application.

Can anyone help me please? I have spend a lot of time in azure  documentations without any success.

I think I must to connect my Azure VM in azure remoteapp collection but I don't know how!

Thank you

Comment: I think it should be `%SYSTEMDRIVE%` rather than `%SYSTEMDRIVER%` (notice the R at the end). Please verify that is correct.

Comment: Can you please also post a screenshot of the error that you are getting?

Comment: And also, people might be able to help you more here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/home?forum=AzureRemoteApp :)

Answer (score 1):

you are close, you must create a custom image and then import that image into azure RemoteApp image library and then create a Azure RemoteApp collection specifying that image.  Read here for more information = https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/remoteapp-imageoptions/